# Eloquent query to get count of grouped related model

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have an `Action` model which has many `UserAction`s. I need to get the count of how many `UserActions` there are for each `Action`. An SQL for this is:

```sql
SELECT *, count(*) as count
FROM user_actions JOIN actions
    ON user_actions.action_id=actions.id
GROUP BY actions.id;
```

And I was just wondering if there is a way to do this in Eloquent query?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you meant `GROUP BY actions.type;` in your code, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it, this is the closest I can get to as few raw queries (or as Eloquent-y) as possible.

```
UserAction::select(DB::raw('actions.id, actions.name, COUNT(*) AS count'))
                    ->join('actions', 'actions.id', '=', 'user_actions.action_id')
                    ->groupBy('actions.id')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have your `userActions` relationship setup in your `Action` model.

Ex.: (Assuming you have a `UserAction` model in namespace `App`)

```
class Action extends Model 
{
    public function userActions() 
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\UserAction');
    }
}
```

Then, it is as easy as doing this:

```
//$action = some action

$count = $action->userActions->count();
```

Eloquent relationships return collections: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

And `count` is a method provided by Eloquent collections (Laravel collections): https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/collections#method-count

Comment: OP asked how to count each related action by type. You are just counting all actions in general.

Comment: OP never mentioned anything about action types. I have no idea where you got this from. Pleas read his question again.

Comment: Your right, there is nothing said about action types. But OP asked `count of how many UserActions there are for each Action` which implies to me that there must be different kinds of actions. If he just wants to count the number of actions that are related to a user, then there is no need for `group_by` and your question is correct.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Instead, causes confusion.

Comment: How about grouping it with userActionsName?

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Laravel 5.2 you can use `withCount` method for One to Many relationships.

From the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

> If you want to count the number of results from a relationship without actually loading them you may use the withCount method, which will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting models. For example:

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();

foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

In your situation, if you have setup the relation, something like this should work:

```
$user_actions = App\UserActions::withCount('actions')->get();

foreach ($user_actions as $action) {
    echo $action->actions_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get the count of how many UserActions there are for each
>   Action

Assuming a `UserAction` can have different kind of actions and they are distinguishable by a `action.type` column, than you can count the appearence of each `Action` with Laravel by

```
UserAction::select(DB::raw('actions.type, actions.name, COUNT(*) AS count'))
                    ->join('actions', 'actions.id', '=', 'user_actions.action_id')
                    ->groupBy('actions.type')->get();
```

If `action.action_id` is equal to `action.type` then you can simplify it to

```
UserAction::select(DB::raw('action_id,  COUNT(*) AS count'))
            ->groupBy('action_id')->get();
```